# How do I export/import all the relations created by Relation module?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, entities

There are standard procedures to export/import relation types, but not for the relations themselves. At least, I couldn't find any. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

Export/Import of entities is something that is not standardized and there are many methods of approaching the problem. This is also something Drupal 8 is attempting to solve.

Currently you want to look at [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) and [UUID Features](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) are your best bet. Neither have stable D7 releases, but I played around with deploy and using the views plugin I was able to export entities.

The primary issues with content (entities vs configuration) is that content many times needs to be merged from one server to another so it ends up being a fairly complicated proposition.

Comment: Deploy looks promising, but I wasn't able to do even basic operations wit the latest Feb 17th release. Which release did you use??

Comment: I had to modify it in D7 just to get it working. I am not sure of the current what it's current state. If anything you may want to look through issues. Or ping one of the devs in IRC.

Comment: Do you have the code put up somewhere, github etc?

Comment: I modified it to try it out a while back and I have no idea what happened to it. I know I commented in one of the issues, maybe with a patch. Sorry, I couldn't be of more help.